# Best / Safest way to stop and start slapd

Tags: slapd

Im running OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.25.

What is the best way to stop and start it ?

I want to copy the LDAP database and have  read I need to stop slapd first.

Distro used is Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your distribution something along the line of `service slapd stop` or `service openldap stop` or similar.

Give us more infos if you want a better answer (e.g. distro used).

Comment: Im running Ubuntu 11.04  distribution

Comment: Then `service slapd start|stop` should work.